# I am getting an error in PostgreSQL when trying to import csv "ERROR: extra data after last expected column CONTEXT: COPY netflixmovies,

Tags: postgresql, csv, import-csv

This is the full error

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT: COPY netflixmovies, line 2: "1,Movie,Dick Johnson Is Dead,Kirsten Johnson,,United States,2021-09-25,2020,PG-13,90 min,Documentari..."
```

I am not sure what is wrong but this is just the second row it is referring to and I am not sure what the problem is. Someone please help, thank you :). For context I am using PGadmin4, Windows 10, PostgreSQL, and am trying to import a csv file to a table.

I was trying to import a csv file and was expecting to get no errors, however I got an error that says extra data after last expected column and I am not sure what it means. Heads up, I created 12 columns and there are 12 columns in the csv file so there shouldnt be any issues as far as there being extra data after last expected column. What am I missing?

Comment: Please revise the question by adding the table details, input data, and command. There isn't enough information to determine the reason.

Comment: perhaps a title (or other text) has a comma in it so when parsing the file it produces an unexpected extra column? hard to help when we don't have the actual first 3 lines of the file (headings if present, data lines 1 & 2). aslo the DDL of the table you are using